# Issue With Overlapping UIViews and Interactivity with UIKit/Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uikit

I am building an interface in Swift and UIKit targeting iOS. All of my views are programmatically constructed. I am having an issue where a `UIView` that overlaps another `UIView` (but does not completely cover it) prevents any tap events from passing through. The layout looks like this:

[image: "Interface"]

The navbar at the bottom is a custom view and functions fine. Tapping those buttons changes the active view behind it (the current view is the `TextView` with the SQL syntax highlighting). Above it is a `UILabel` (with the text "Connected") and a `UIView` (the circle with the gradient background). I will refer to this element as the "ButtonView" and the label as the "StatusView". The "StatusView" is anchored to the navbar and the enclosing view, and the "ButtonView" is anchored to the navbar and the "StatusView".

This is the relevant layout code:

```swift
            view.addSubview(navBar!)
            view.addSubview(status)
            view.addSubview(button)

            status.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            status.layer.masksToBounds = true
            status.text = "Example String"
            status.textColor = .white
            status.layer.cornerRadius = 20.0
            status.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10.0, left: 10.0, bottom: 10.0, right: 10.0)

            button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            button.layer.masksToBounds =    true
            button.layer.cornerRadius = 35.0
    //        button.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    //        button.backgroundColor = .white

            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                status.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: navBar!.topAnchor, constant: -10.0),
                status.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 10.0),
                status.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -90.0),
                status.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50.0),
                button.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: navBar!.topAnchor, constant: -10.0),
                button.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: status.trailingAnchor, constant: 10.0),
                button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 70.0),
                button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 70.0)
                ])
```

The intended behavior is that even with the "ButtonView" present, the SQL view can still be tapped and edited. However, when the "ButtonView" is present, the SQL view can no longer be focused. If the "ButtonView"'s `isUserInteractionEnabled` property is set to `false` or the "ButtonView" is removed, everything behaves correctly. The "StatusView" does not seem to have any adverse effects, without having to edit any of its properties. (Note that there is no gestural behavior currently assigned to the "ButtonView", and that is not a `UIButton`). The debug view does not seem to show any overlapping layers:

[image: "Debug View"]

Ideally, I would like to eventually add a gesture recognizer to this view, but wondering if that will forever disallow me from accessing the views that are further in the background? Is it possible to overlap interactive views like this, or am I somehow screwing up the responder chain?

Comment: I have a question, if you create the views programmatically, why did you use the constraints?

You can only use the width and the height of the screen or the view and then set the x and y position.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. The constraints are there to correctly layout the views? By "programmatically", I mean without Interface Builder.